# How to make the progress bar with html css javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to make the progress bar Like the image below

[image]

Comment: May be using `transform: scale()` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "make"? Re-create the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to use something like:

css:

```
.progress
{
    position:relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.progressUnder
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('backgroundUnder.jpg');
}

.progressOver
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0%;
    background-image: url('backgroundOver.jpg');
}

.progressPercent
{
    position:absolute;
    top: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

and html:

```
<div class='progress'>
  <div class='progressUnder'/>
  <div class='progressOver' />
  <div class='progressPercent'>0%</div>
</div>
```

and then use javascript to animate the percent height of div.progressOver, as well as the .progressPercent counter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a animation I think. 
Aswell as The Molecule says.  You need to use height for that color.  I guess you know how an normal one works.  First try to out create a circle,  use the height as The Molecule explained,  then you need to make the inside of the circle transparent/unneeded.  As that is done the heights will be displayed in the circle.  That how you do it,  never done it myself tho since i dont use custom  loading bars.